# Using Angularjs-Toaster inside the decorator of $exceptionHandler

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-decorator, angularjs-config

I am trying to toast errors those are handled in the $exceptionHandler decorator as follows,

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',['toaster']);

app.config(function($provide){
  $provide.decorator('$exceptionHandler',function($delegate,toaster){
    toaster.pop('error','text','error');
    $delegate(exception, cause);
  });
});
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/18zHTNBO9mZ4x3RthDuN?p=preview) is the plunkr.
This is giving me the following error,

```
Error: [$injector:cdep] Circular dependency found: $rootScope <- toaster <- $exceptionHandler <- $rootScope
```

I am using [AngularJS-Toaster](https://github.com/jirikavi/AngularJS-Toaster) for showing errors. How can I inject toaster service inside the decorator now?

Comment: Hi I'm having the same issue, did you find any solution?

Comment: @DRB you should mark David's answer as the correct one

Answer (score 8):

You can inject the `$injector` into your decorator and wrap your injection in a function.  This delays the injection of the toaster service until you invoke the `$exceptionHandler`, preventing a circular dependency.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',['toaster']);

app.config(function($provide){
    $provide.decorator('$exceptionHandler',function($delegate,$injector){
        return function (exception, cause) {
            var toaster = $injector.get('toaster'); 
            toaster.pop('error','text','error');
        }
    });
});
```

To expand on ***why*** this is a circular dependency, you have to look at what is being required by both the injected service, as well as what is occurring in the decorator.

The `toaster` service has a dependency on `$rootScope` and is being injected into the decorator for for `$exceptionHandler`.  However, `$rootScope` in turn has a dependency on `$exceptionHandler`.  This ends up creating a circular reference.

You would find the same behavior if `$http` or `$q` was injected instead of `toaster` since they also have dependencies on `$rootScope`.  it isn't `toaster` specifically that is the issue...rather it is the `$rootScope` dependency while trying to also apply behavior to a dependency ***of*** `$rootScope`.

Comment: would you be so kind as to explain why there is a circular reference?

Comment: thanks for taking the time to do that, great explanation